# Connecto to SQL Server with c# and JDBC

Tags: java, c#, jdbc, visual-c#-express-2010, windows-xp-sp3

I have this program in `java` to connect to a `SQL Server`

```
server = "ZF-SQL-MTRAZDB.NIS.LOCAL"
dbName = "MRAZ"
nameBaseDatos = "CD_LO"
table = "dbo.CD_LO_DATA"
user = "user"
password = "Pass"
url = "jdbc:sqlserver//"+ server + "\\" + dbName + "jdatabaseName=" +     nameBaseDatos
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc_SQLServerDriver"
```

Now I have to do the same with `Visual C# 2010` in `Windows XP`

How can I do this program?? Because in java use `JDBC`, Should I also use `JDBC`?

Thanks for all!

Comment: Use `SqlConnection` to connect to `SQL Server` , take a look at this page : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: And I use this: `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);`
        `command.Connection.Open();`
        `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` but What is `queryString`? and `connection`? The `URL`?? The `server`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ConnectionString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is similar to an `OLE DB` connection string, but is not identical. Unlike OLE DB or ADO, the connection string that is returned is the same as the user-set `ConnectionString`, minus security information if the Persist Security Info value is set to false (default). The .NET Framework Data Provider for `SQL Server` does not persist or return the password in a connection string unless you set Persist Security Info to true.

You can use the `ConnectionString` property to connect to a database. The following example illustrates a typical connection string.

```
"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Northwind;server=(local)"
```

Use the new [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) to construct valid connection strings at run time.

```
private static void OpenSqlConnection()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

        connection.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
        Console.WriteLine("ConnectionString: {0}",
            connection.ConnectionString);
    }
}

static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    // To avoid storing the connection string in your code,  
    // you can retrieve it from a configuration file. 
    return "Data Source=MSSQL1;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;"
        + "Integrated Security=true;";
}
```

1. `Data Source` or `Server or`Address`or`Addr`or`Network Address
   `: The name or network address of the instance of SQL Server to which
   to connect. The port number can be specified after the server name :`
   server=tcp:servername, portnumber`
2. The `Initial Catalog` or `Database` : The name of the database. The database name can be 128 characters or less.
3. The `Integrated Security` or `Trusted_Connection` : When `false`, `User ID` and `Password` are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication. Recognized values are true, `false`, yes, no, and `sspi` (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to `true`. If `User ID` and `Password` are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the `User ID` and `Password` will be ignored and `Integrated Security` will be used.

and [other items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I hope this help you :) .